# internet explorer: download a binary file using ajax 'GET' call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi i am new to ajax and js. i have to silently download(no prompt) a binary file (acyually .zip) and save it on my local machine.
i am able to get the data from server:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open('GET', downloadURL , true);
xmlhttp.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    var typedData = new Uint8Array(xmlhttp.response),
    alert(typedData );      
    }
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

I now need to save this data on my local machine to a specified path. i am not able to do that.
also i have to run this on internet explorer 10.

new thought: but yes c++ allows you to create a file. so if somehow i pass the data i have from js to c++ code, probably i can achieve what i want :) [PS: simpler way would have been to download it in c++ code but i cant do that because of the authentication mechanism i use]

Comment: why an ajax request? if you did a simple `window.location=downloadUrl`-type thing, you'd get your browser's save prompt

Comment: i want to do a silent doownload. so doont want browser's prompt

Comment: sounds kind of sketchy

Comment: so you want to be able to dump arbitrary files on the user's computer without their knowledge? That would *NEVER* get abused, right?

Comment: no they wont. they will be in temp folder and i would be deleting them later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible for security reasons. Javascript cannot directly save a file to the local machine. That would be a feature hackers would love to take advantage of.

Comment: the url i am using for downloading uses authentication. is it still not possible?

Comment: It's still impossible. Imagine a scenario where I send you a link to my page, you visit it, then I have javascript running on load to download a virus from my page to save onto your computer, without any user interaction. I've not only infected your computer, but done it completely without you realizing it. The request to download could have been authenticated, but that doesn't change the fact that it was a request that the user didn't intend.

Comment: also i already have fetched the data. it is with me. i just need to save it on filesystem